# zsh shell fg command coming from bash?

Tags: bash, zsh

Is there a way to edit the fg command so that it behaves like the one bash uses?

Instead of having:

```
fg %<job number>
```

in zsh, can I have:

```
fg <job number>
```

as in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own function, `fg`, to check the arg and then run
the builting `fg`:

```
fg(){ if [[ "$*" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then builtin fg %"$*";else builtin fg "$@";fi }
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the statement that pops up after you use "fg 1"?

For example, when using just "fg 2", I get:

[2] + 15169 continued emacs .zshrc

in the terminal, followed by a suspended line after I Ctrl-z out of the window. That doesn't happen with the default "fg %2"

Comment: Oh, excuse me, it does happen with both %2 and 2. Is there a way to remove that line?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to suppress the message.